# TFS2015 vNext build "build check in policy"

Tags: build, tfs-2015

The build check in policy does not seem to work with TFS2015 vNext CI build. 
Is this expected? Or is there any extra configuration needed?

Thank you!

Angel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. There will not be any **policy warnings** if the last vNext build failed. The "build check in policy" only works with XAML build definition for now.

As a workaround, you could use gated check-in build with vNext build.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! We have both Gated\CI build enabled to run different things. The build check in policy has been very useful to remind people last CI build was failed (more useful then email alerts), do you know if any plan to have this available for vNext build? Thanks again!